# Full Calendar rows by city using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fullcalendar

Hi I am implementing a full calendar feature in an application. As shown in the following plunker.

http://plnkr.co/edit/AtmzLrn81FsxJxyc5rzd?p=preview

```
<body>
    <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
      <div id="calendar" ui-calendar="calendarConfig" ng-model="eventSources"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Currently the calendar is displaying "Time" row-wise under heading of "all-day"
I want to change all-day to cities, so that on each row I have city names instead of time. Please let me know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no way to achieve this through fullcalendar's standard interface. If you are looking for something, which allows you to draw graphs and manipulate the y-axis labels take a look at [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org). If you still want to use fullcalendar you will have to dive into its source.

In your version of fullcalendar (1.6.1) the corresponding lines should be:

line 3165

```
"<th class='" + headerClass + " fc-agenda-axis'>" + opt('allDayText') + "</th>" +
```

and line 3215 - 3217

```
"<th class='fc-agenda-axis " + headerClass + "'>" +
((!slotNormal || !minutes) ? formatDate(d, opt('axisFormat')) : '&nbsp;') +
</th>" +
```